# Whats the purpose of n in where clause in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employees Emp1 
WHERE (n) = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary)) 
              FROM Employees Emp2 
              WHERE Emp2.Salary >= Emp1.Salary )
```

Comment: What "flavor" of SQL is this? I've never seen anything like that... is this Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQLite? Something else?

Comment: this is the Mysql Query find the nth salary from the table

Comment: my funny guess: (n) is a column in table

Comment: Replace the `n` with a number.

Comment: according to vijay, nth record

Comment: finding (n)th salary from table means it must be any number or last record in a table.Generally if table contains number of records then finding any value from table called with (n)th value.

Comment: let assume n=2, I have a employees table having salary detail and this query give me the 2nd highest salary record from the employee table so its not the number of columns(n) in this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what matters most is the subquery. It returns number of distinct salary that is greater than or equals to current `Emp1.Salary`. This value returned is equal to the employee's salary rank.

Assume that you're the employee with third greatest salary, 10000. The subquery will count number of distinct salary that is greater than you which is `2`, plus one (`2+1=3`). Plus one counted from employee, including your self, having salary equals to 10000. This is because `>=` used in the `WHERE` clause.

Having said that, it makes perfect sense that the entire query select employee based on his salary rank.